# Rails 5: undefined method `megabytes' for 64:Integer when using in config/environment/staging.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

As explained in [Caching with Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore) I added the following line to `config/environment/staging.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
...
  config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
...
end
```

This raised the error when starting Puma server:

```
undefined method `megabytes' for 64:Integer
```

Requiring the corresponding `acctive_suport` module on the top of `staging.rb`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/bytes'
...
```

solved the issue.

What am I missing ? Thank you.

Used Rails version: `5.2.2`, API mode.
Ruby: `2.6.1`.